# Chrome 54 Broke Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, google-chrome

I inherited a code base that just broke with the Chrome 54 update. It has an input fields that are validating each character as it is typed. With each char. entered, it exits the field, checks the value, and places the cursor back in the field.

With version 54, Chrome is setting the caret position back to 0, so the cursor is never placed back into the field. That results in the user only being able to type one character before having to click back into the field again.

Example field:

```
<span id="individual" class="inputROW" ng-show="person.IsIndividual">
    <span class="inputROW">
        <input type="text" name="fullname" size="18" maxlength="50"
               placeholder="Full Name"
               ng-model="person.FullName"
               ng-bind="person.FullName"
               ng-change="setIsDirty()"
               ng-pattern-restrict="^[-A-Za-z,. ]*$">
    </span>
</span>
```

The problem seems to be in the NG Pattern Restrict code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kilpatrick/gym35puc/)). Looks like that code was sourced from [this repo](https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict).

I tried bypassing the validation completely by wiping the pattern restrict file. That does stop validation, but the Chrome user is still exited from (& not returned to) the input. Removing the `ng-model` from the HTML input allows the user to type normally. However, that also results in no data being saved.

---

**Working:** Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer | 
**Fails:** Chrome 54, Opera 41

Comment: What is your ngChange function doing? It doesn't sound like you have attempted to remove that. I'm also not sure why you would manually need to do that either...

Comment: I think that's updating the class to angular's `ng-dirty` (i.e. user has modified field). It's still updated to dirty without `ng-change` on the field's HTML. The error persists after deleting all `ng-`s except `ng-model`. So, the issue is seemingly not in the pattern restrict file.